# IIS 7 Windows Server 2008 password protect

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis

Generally speaking I am PHP developer working on Apache. I have however taken on new site, that is built in ASP.net(VB) and is obviously running on IIS. I have set up a subdomain, and I wanting to password protect this domain, so only myself and people I allow will be able to access the domain.

Normally on apache I could do this sort of thing with a .htaccess and .htpassword file. I know that I could make .htaccess work on IIS but I do not to have to fight to make something work, when I am sure that someone will be able to tell that is a built in way in IIS to do this.

Could someone shed any light on how to lock my website down, so I can create a username and password so I can lock my domain down while in beta?

Comment: Why the downvote? My question is clear, concise and in now way ambigous?

Comment: some might interpret it as not being "programming" related and want to see it moved to ServerFault. Personally, it's all kinda blurry, so I'll help reverse that down vote ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, though not a direct correlation, the .htaccess equivalent in IIS is your web.Config file.

To get this working, you'll need to enable Windows Authentication in your Web.Config.

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
```

And you can set who's authorized like this.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="domainname\Managers" />
      <allow users="domainname\user1,domainname\user2,domainname\user3" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[Here's a more detailed instruction](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication), as well as [here](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/323176) and [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/authentication-and-authorization-with-windows-accounts-in-asp.net/)